# Being a mug with masonry.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, masonry

I think I'm probably doing something wrong that's incredibly obvious...

This is my HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item w2"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item w2"></div>
<div class="item h2"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item h2"></div>
<div class="item w2 h2"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item h2"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I'm calling jQuery 1.7.1 and modernizr in the head, and calling masonry.js and the below script before the /body

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').masonry({
        columnWidth: 440,
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isFitWidth: false,
        transitionDuration: 0,
    });
  });
```

Incidentally my CSS is below if that makes any difference

```
#container {padding: 5px;}
.item {
    width: 220px;
    height: 160px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #CCC;
  }
.item.w2 {width: 440px;}
.item.h2 { height: 280px;}
```

No console errors but doesn't seem to be stacking how I would imagine

** see here - http://www.rsg-media.com/masonry/test.html

I would think it would appear a bit more like this

http://www.code-pal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/masonry-css3-jquery-fallback.jpg

...or am I being an idiot?

Comment: you'll have to give a bit more info on the "imagine" bit for those of us that aren't mind readers.

Comment: ah yes fair point! will edit now... sorry...

Answer (score 0):

done a snippet here, changed the width of w2 to a percentage and it moved them around a bit better... I've reset it to original now but I think there's your problem

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
    $('#container').masonry({
        columnWidth: 440,
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isFitWidth: false,
        transitionDuration: 0,
    });
  });
```

```css
#container {padding: 5px;}
.item {
    width: 220px;
    height: 160px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #CCC;
  }
.item.w2 {width: 440px;}
.item.h2 { height: 280px;}
```

```html
<script src="http://desandro.github.io/masonry/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item w2"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item w2"></div>
<div class="item h2"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item h2"></div>
<div class="item w2 h2"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item h2"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```